# Load excel Ribbon on demand

Tags: c#, office-interop, ribbon, excel-addins

I would like to add functionality to my Excel addin so I could load different Ribbons on demand.

At the moment I am trying  by exporting the ribbon to XML and loading it

```
private Microsoft.Office.Core.IRibbonExtensibility ribbonObj;
protected override Microsoft.Office.Core.IRibbonExtensibility CreateRibbonExtensibilityObject()
{
    DialogResult RibbonToLoad = MessageBox.Show("Yes = V2  No = V3", "Select Version", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
    switch (RibbonToLoad)
    {
        case DialogResult.Yes:
           ribbonObj = new RibbonV2();
           return ribbonObj;
        case DialogResult.No:
           ribbonObj = new RibbonV3();
           return ribbonObj;
     }

    return new RibbonV2();
}
```

The problema with this is I cannot find how to switch this Ribbon. I don't find it inside the `Globals.` object.

Also I tried without exporting to XML, but also I couldn't achieve the load on demand of a different ribbon while running(e.g. clicking a button on a WPF window...)

Any idea how to get this? I would like to have the possibility of loading different ribbons on the same addin(but only one would be present at once)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't manage the process of loading ribbon controls. But you can change visibility of your controls at runtime. The IRibbonUI interface provides the [Invalidate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.core.iribbonui.invalidate(v=office.14).aspx) and InvalidateControl methods that allow to trigger your callbacks where you can change visibility at runtime (getVisible).

In the following example, starting the host application triggers the onLoad event procedure that then calls a procedure which creates an object representing the Ribbon UI. Next, a callback procedure is defined that invalidates all of the controls on the UI and then refreshes the UI.

The following is the XML markup for Office to load the custom ribbon:

```
<customUI … onLoad=”MyAddInInitialize” …>
```

The following is the callback method for the onLoad event:

```
Dim MyRibbon As IRibbonUI

Sub MyAddInInitialize(Ribbon As IRibbonUI)
    Set MyRibbon = Ribbon
End Sub

Sub myFunction()
    ‘ Invalidates the caches of all of this add-in’s controls 
    MyRibbon.Invalidate()            
End Sub
```

You can read more about the Ribbon UI in the following series of articles in MSDN:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338202(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338199(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa722523(v=office.12).aspx)

Comment: But If I override the `CreateRibbonExtensibilityObject` and return the first time a com object... where is this object? With your solution then it is like I just need one ribbon and play with showing/hiding controls, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, you can't add multiple customizations. The IRibbonExtensibility interface is called once.

Comment: And could it be posible to add elements to the current ribbon?

Comment: What current the ribbon are you talking about?

Comment: After startup and the loading of the ribbon. Now I use a ribbon(design) instead of the xml. I just tried and got errors because the `items` collections are readonly.

Comment: Ribbon UI is static thing. The only possible dynamism is callbacks.